# How to call a php script based on values in an array

Tags: php

I have a set of variables that have randomly assigned values.

E.g.,

```
$a = 1;
$b = -1;
$c = 2;
```

And I have a script that corresponds to each variable.

E.g.,

```
a.php for $a
b.php for $b
c.php for $c
```

I want to run the script that corresponds with the variable that has the greatest value. So, in this case, I want to run c.php because $c has the greatest value among the three variables.

Thank you so much,
Peter

Edit: This is what I have. I've basically put the variables in an array and sorted them from highest to lowest according to the value. But this doesn't solve my problem. I want to run a corresponding php file.

```
$var = array( 'a' => $a, 'b' => $b, 'c' => $c);
arsort($var);
```

Comment: Have you tried something ?

Comment: What do you want do say with 'run' the script?

Comment: Welcome to SO. With a better explanation, surely you find the solution in a jiffy! Recomended start: http://stackoverflow.com/tour and http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. I invite you to rethink the question by explaining better what you want to achieve and what you've done so far.

Comment: I have a php script corresponding to each variable. I want to "call" or "execute" or "run" the php script that corresponds to the variable that has the highest value. (I'm a noob, so maybe I'm getting the wording wrong.)

Comment: Now what do you mean with "run", include ? (Can you make an example what is in the file which you want to run?)

Comment: If you explain what @Rizier123 asked, i think we can help you better. Do you want do include the file or run it using curl or a shell command?

Answer (score 1):

You can get the greatest value using:

```
$a = 1;
$b = -1;
$c = 2;

$files = array(
    $a => 'a.php',
    $b => 'b.php',
    $c => 'c.php'
);

ksort($files);

echo 'Correct file: ' . array_pop($files);
```

References:

[ksort()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ksort.php)

[array_pop()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-pop.php)

Comment: This doesn't answer OP's question! Where is the relation to the variables and the file names?!

Comment: Still only with the greatest value he can't execute file "c.php" then?!

Comment: @Rizier123, He needs to specify better what mean 'execute', can be an include, curl and other. With the correct file, i think he can go ahead.

Comment: But how does he gets the file `c.php` with the value `3` ?

Comment: @Rizier123, I made another improvement

Comment: The `$files` array is just nowhere related to the values of the variables! So if `$a` has the biggest value it will still choose `c.php`!

Comment: This would only work if you had an associative array that links `$a`, `$b`, `$c` up to the expected file name. So that way, after popping the max value of `$values`, you could then call `$array[$max]` and get the file.

Comment: @Rizier123, I think now it's okay

Comment: @MasterOdin, I made a change, i think now it's okay

Comment: @MarcioSimao, I'm a novice, so I don't really understand the solution. Can someone please provide me a run-down?

Comment: @marciosimao, what you have selects the highest value, but how does it run the php file?

Comment: @peter, How do you want to run it?

Comment: @MarcioSimao, well, there are three files named 'a.php', 'b.php', and 'c.php' that correspond to each variable. Each php file would do something different, and I want it to run if its corresponding variable is highest.